# Track page views of google colab

Tags: google-analytics, google-colaboratory

I’m trying to determine how to add Google Analytics tracking code to my Google Colab pages. I do not need to pull GA data within Colab…I want to see if people are viewing the pages. I have linked several from my portfolio and am interested in seeing whether there’s any traffic.